chrono usage wirh timezone
I have a duration as string e.g. "13:00:00" and a time_point parsed to a utc_time from an UTC time string using std::chrono::parse function.
Now given this duration and a timezone e.g. "America/New_York". How to compare my time_point to today duration as time point using UTC as common timezone.
The documentation tz of cppreference chrono is not yet completed.

A duration is not a point in time  (e.g. an hour is an hour everywhere) so it is unclear what you want to compare.

I want to convert my duration to a time_point (today) using the provided timezone then convert this time_point to UTC

How to compare 45 minutes to 14:12 o'clock? This doesn't make sense.

Are you asking to do today + duration? As others have said, comparing doesn't make sense.

I would say a time_point that represent 24-09-2024-13:00:00 if today is 24-09-2024 sorry to be unclear

I've attempted to add extra verbose comments so that no further explanation is needed:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    // Inputs
    
    // duration as string
    string tod_s = "13:00:00";
    // Some utc_time from UTC string
    utc_seconds tp_utc = floor<seconds>(clock_cast<utc_clock>(system_clock::now()) + 6h);
    // Some time zone
    string tz_s = "America/New_York";

    // Compare today's midnight in time zone + duration against utc_time

    // Convert tod_s to duration
    istringstream in{tod_s};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    seconds tod;
    in >> parse("%T", tod);

    // Get pointer to time_zone
    auto tz = locate_zone(tz_s);

    // Get local midnight of today
    auto local_mid = floor<days>(tz->to_local(system_clock::now()));
    // Add duration to get local time point
    auto tp_local = local_mid + tod;

    // Convert local time to sys_time, and then to utc_time
    auto tp = clock_cast<utc_clock>(tz->to_sys(tp_local));

    // Compare tp and tp_utc
    bool b = tp > tp_utc;
}

A comment though:  You might want to use sys_time in place of utc_time.  sys_time is what computers normally traffic in.  utc_time adds leap seconds to it.  You really only want to do this when you know that you need the leap seconds in.  This is typically for spacecraft or astronomical applications.
To change to using sys_time, simply remove the clock_cast to utc_time at the last step.

thank you for your help. I have just a question if the string I parsed is in UTC time. Using sys_time does make sense ?

Yes, you can parse a civil calendar time_point in UTC into a sys_time.  In fact that should be your first choice.  The only situation where this will not do the right thing is if the string has a "60" in the seconds field.

Okay very clear. Thank you again :)

utc_seconds tp_utc becomes : sys_seconds tp_sys

actually the tp_utc is streamed from a grpc client with a rate of 10k protobuf msg/s and my tp_local is computed in my local server at startup. This code is not considering UTC offset changes. What's the best way (seeking efficiency) to compare my two dates without converting my tp_utc to the target timezone upon reciept of each protobuf msg

I may be misunderstanding, but I think this answer stands as the most efficient solution.  It sounds like you've got one (or few) tp_local computed at start up.  Convert it (them) to UTC (you probably want sys_time not utc_time, but I can't know that for sure).  And then compare the incoming tp_utc to that (those) converted tp_local.
